# Using Camera with google_mlkit_barcode_scanning in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter, I have used ML-KIT BARCODE SCANNING in Ionic Framework to scan barcodes using the camera directly, but now i would like to add the scanning functionality to an existing flutter app, all the tutorials i found on the internet are showing how to do that by reading the barcode from an image picked from gallery and not from the camera directly.

Is it possible to use the camera directly to scan a barcodes using `google_mlkit_barcode_scanning` in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!
You cant try with this example
https://github.com/flutter-ml/google_ml_kit_flutter/tree/master/packages/example
you just need to run this flutter project to test it